# Spectrum of Rotated Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, with $\Re(\alpha) , \Im(\alpha)>0$ and $H$ the operator defined in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by

$$H(u):= -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u +\alpha x^2u.$$

How can I show that the spectrum of $H$ coincides with its point spectrum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's kind of funny to have $\alpha$ being complex.

Comment: You have to check the details, but I think the (very nice) proof for positive potentials given in Simon, *Schrödinger operator with purely discrete spectrum* also goes through in this case (I think it's enough to assume $\Re(\alpha)>0$).